# How to modify the observed values in python's holidays library

Tags: python

I am not sure how to modify the 'observed' values in holidays. I need a holiday to be observed on a Monday only if it falls on a Sunday i.e. 12-25-2016(Sunday) then 12-26-2016 is observed. However, I do not want a holiday to be observed on a Monday if it was on a Saturday, or a holiday be observed on a Saturday if it is on a Friday. i.e. 12-25-2015(Friday) then 12-26-2015 is observed. Those two example I got from testing the holidays library. I checked the documentation and could only find how to turn the observed holidays off. I just want to modify the observed values not remove.
Thank you for all the help. I am new to the holiday's library, so please pardon my noobness